# Is it necessary to do all arithmetic operations for filtering images in one line for C? for CS50 filter-less

Tags: c, image, bitmap, computer-science, cs50

I've been doing the "filter-less" problem for CS50 and noticed that, this code:

```
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtGreen) / 3;

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

and this one,

```
// Convert image to grayscale
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtGreen);

            // Notice this line
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue /= 3;

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Have entirely different outputs, and the former gives better results. Can someone explain the reason behind that? Why is the difference when the arithmetic operation is done in separate lines? Do correct me if I am doing something wrong here.

The program is supposed to take an input image in BMP format, apply filters (In this case Greyscale) and create an output, the function takes the image's height `height` and width `width` and the RGB values of the said image in the array `image`.

This is from CS50's Introduction to computer science course Week 4 by the way.

[EDIT]

```
typedef uint8_t  BYTE;
```

```
typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

More information regarding the question is here:

https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/4/filter/less/

Comment: What is the definition of `RGBTRIPLE`? Specifically what is the type of `rgbtBlue`? If it is an `int` then there should be no difference. If it is a `char` then the stored result in the second example is restricted to the range of a char which will truncate it before the division.

Comment: Edit the code to provide a [mre], including definition of `RGBTRIPLE`. Also provide a link to the problem statement and supporting files, such as any provided files that define `RGBTRIPLE`.

Comment: `RGBTRIPLE` is a structure containing `rgbtBlue` , `rgbtRed` , `rgbtGreen` which is in BYTE data type. where BYTE is defined with `typedef uint8_t  BYTE;` in that program. I guess it means BYTE is an uint8_t type.

Comment: Yeah kk lemme do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtGreen` is larger than `uint8_t` can cope with. And

> ```
> image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtGreen) / 3;
> ```

assigns, for example, `417/3` (or `139`, operations here are done with `int`) to the member

> ```
> image[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtGreen);
> image[i][j].rgbtBlue /= 3;
> ```

first assigns `417 % 256` (or `161`) to the member, then divides that by `3`